# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am facing a problem with my WCF service when i'm trying to save large text by using Tinymce Editor,
It says **The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.**

Max sizes is already in the configurations, is there anything else that i am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Endpoint is following,

```
<endpoint name="LabServiceEndPoint" address="***" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EasternLabs.Common.Contract.ServiceContracts.ILabServices" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" />
```

My Binding,

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <security mode="None" />
          <readerQuotas
                 maxDepth="2147483647"
                 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                 maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: May be you should split up your LARGE TEXT since it clearly say REQUEST entity is too large. Doing this will have it's benefits too.

Comment: Is there no any workaround to make it work without splinting the Text ?

Comment: none that i can think of.

Comment: Is it REST Service???

Comment: No @shankar.parsanamoni

Comment: Remove  <readerQuotas> Tag then try it.

Comment: @shankar.parsanamoni i removed but no luck :(

Comment: Please update your web.config total code,I thing there is a problem in endpoint binding.I agree with maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

Comment: I have done with lot of things, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your config seems to be OK so I think your problem is MaxRequestEntityAllowed

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/468d6cea-04cd-4b10-b1e1-c17b9e909d07.mspx?mfr=true

Try it set via cmd

```
cmd appcmd set config /section:asp /maxRequestEntityAllowed:4294967295
```

It will set it to 4gb - change the number if you want lower limits.

This is not good for DoS